# Should particle board treads be removed before finishing my stairs?

Tags: stairs

The. Builder installed temporary stairs of particle board. 
Should we remove these prior to installing the
Permanent stairs and risers?

Comment: You should really revise to explain what sort of stairs you're building. It matters whether you're carpeting them, overlaying laminate or tile, or putting in full hardwood.

Comment: A couple of pictures would be great with this question. The question that comes to my mind is, "If they are 'temporary stairs' that the builder put in, why didn't the builder put in the permanent treads and risers to finish the job?"

Answer (score 1):

Purpose-built bullnose 1-1/4" particle board treads are a common and perfectly acceptable permanent tread solution. They've been the standard under carpeting in my region since at least the 1980s.

[image]

<sub>[image source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiU5IGS8P3jAhXFVc0KHaoeBHEQjhx6BAgBEAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.weekesforest.com%2Fproducts%2Fbuilding-products-and-cedar-roofing%2Fparticleboard-osb-stair-treads-wi%2F&psig=AOvVaw3HfglmGz601S23EDjXrWqM&ust=1565717974134409)</sub>

The only time they're a concern is when there's significant moisture contact, but then there are usually other problems of larger magnitude.

Now if you're asking because you're putting in full-thickness (1" or better) hardwood treads, then yes, you'd remove those.